# Confused in looping

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

What code can give me this result?

Copy value in A1, Worksheet 1 to Worksheet 2 column A 4 times (e.g A1 - A4)
Then Copy value in A2, Worksheet 1 to Worksheet 2 column A 4 times again (e.g A5 - A8), and so on.

Thank you!

Comment: ... and so on? I'm sorry, but this site is not a free coding service. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask] a question

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Moveit
'declare your variables
dim r as range
dim t as range
dim i as integer
 'initialise your ranges
set r = worksheets(1).range("A1")
set t = worksheets(2).range("a1")

do  'begin looping
     for i = 1 to 4  'do 4 times
           t=r  
           set t = t.offset(1,0) 'move target down 1
      next i
      set r = r.offset(1,0)  'move source down 1

loop until r= "" 'repeat until you run out of sources

End Sub
```